# Getting blank page after running orchard site in webmatrix

Tags: orchardcms, webmatrix

I have copied the folder of my website and rename it. Now I want to run the newly crated website in webmatrix but when I tried to run the site it showing blank page in the browser.

Comment: Same as your previous exactly-same question, we can't do anything with this information. Include errors, repro steps or any information SO users can make sense of

Comment: @devqon what type of information can I give?

Comment: Look in the 'App_Data\Logs', if Orchard is actually running; you will have log files for the day. that should help you analyse your actual problems and ask a question.

Comment: @ErMasca What I want to find in it?